# Using variables gives error

Tags: c++, variables

I have written a application that renames a file on the server but i want it to rename `log.txt` to random name. Here's my code:

```
int ftpopen(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[], int n)
{
    HINTERNET hInternet;
    HINTERNET hFtp;

    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    hFtp = InternetConnect(hInternet, L"cdata.comule.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, L"a5563949", L"deepa123*", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);

    if (FtpRenameFile(hFtp, L"log.txt", funsys))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Renamed Successful.", L"Title", NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Renamed Failed.", L"Title", NULL);
    }
}
```

`funsys` is a variable `char*` outside this function.

It's giving me this error:

```
    4   IntelliSense: argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"
```

Please help me solve this, I have tried converting `char*` to `LPCWSTR` but it doesn't work.

Comment: -1 for using tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: is this program in php?

Comment: I'm sorry, but my magic crystal won't tell me what `LPCWSTR` is.

Comment: In c++ , I did this to attract attention as i got no replies here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032305/need-help-using-wininet-functions

Comment: that is because LPCWSTR is "const wchar_t*" -> UNICODE and char isn't.

Comment: @thebaconing please help

Comment: @thebaconing Now its giving error ` 4 IntelliSense: argument of type "wchar_t" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR" `

Comment: it is a wchar_t pointer not a single character

Comment: @thebaconing now its showing error ` 4 IntelliSense: a value of type "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const wchar_t *" `

Comment: @thebaconing as i wanted a random number so i did this

Comment: show the code part where you use the "funsys" variable

Comment: @thebaconing `     char *funsys= new char[4];
    funsys="random";

Comment: please edit your question with all the necessary info ( also the code pieces) but I will not discuss this entire matter in the comment section

Comment: @thebaconing So, Won't you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since UNICODE isn't really your frind I'd suggest that you use the "FtpRenameFileA" function instead of the "FtpRenameFile" function. This results in:

```
if (FtpRenameFileA(hFtp,"log.txt",funsys))
{
   MessageBox(NULL, L"Renamed Successful.", L"Title", NULL);
}
else
{
  MessageBox(NULL, L"Renamed Failed.", L"Title", NULL);
}
```

Comment: Will it work, i.e. rename my file?

Comment: I don't know. I just gave you the same function with a different signature

Comment: you should always use TEXT("literal string"); Much more convenient.